# Different behaviour each time I try to create a sparse matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to create a sparse matrix from Triplets. Somehow the program below is either printing a matrix containing only zeros or I get

> ^[[Bterminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc Aborted.

When I add the code at the buttom which is commented out, it starts to work sometimes and sometimes I get again only zeros.

I don't understand this behavior. It seems to be memory related but why should printing out stuff (after commenting in the bottom code) change what happens to the top?

Is there something wrong with my approach? Or is there maybe something wrong with my setup? I just downloaded the latest stable release from http://eigen.tuxfamily.org.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/SparseCore>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
int main() 
{
    int n = 10; 
    std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double> > ijv; 
    for(int i; i < n; i++)
    {
        ijv.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(i,i,1));
        if(i < n-1)
        {
            ijv.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(i+1,i,-0.9));
        }
    }

    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> X(n,n);
    X.setFromTriplets(ijv.begin(), ijv.end());
    std::cout << Eigen::MatrixXd(X) << std::endl;

/*    std::cout << "Row\tCol\tVal" <<std::endl;
    for (int k=0; k < X.outerSize(); ++k)
    {
        for (Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(X,k); it; ++it)
        {
         std::cout << it.row() << "\t"; // row index
         std::cout << it.col() << "\t"; // col index (here it is equal to k)
         std::cout << it.value() << std::endl;
        }
    }
*/


}
```

Comment: `i` needs an initial value.

Comment: Such unpredictability is usually a sign of Undefined Behavior, usually from using uninitialized variables or violating array boundaries. Currently `i` is read from but is uninitialized, and is a likely suspect for the cause of your bug

Comment: Oh, stupid. But why did it not throw an error?

Comment: @Alex if you're starting C++, you'd better get used to serious bugs not causing compiler errors and not throwing exceptions. It's the dark side of the language. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @alterigel Thanks for the hint.

Comment: To avoid accidentally using uninitialized variables, you should always compile with warnings enabled (and of course fix occurring warnings).